# Although rewrite engine is on, I get 404 not found on every page

Tags: permalinks, url-rewriting, 404-error

My wordpress blog has encountered this issue about a week ago. Before that nothing was wrong with it. I got suspicious on web host provider, but they said many times that rewrite engine is on and it works properly.

I ported all source code to my localhost and I have the same issue again. I cannot go to admin section, blogs, etc.

I've read many posts here, but unfortunately gained no success!

What has happened to my blog?

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 .
 .
 .
</IfModule>
```

**EDIT 1:**

RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/vorood/?$ /wp-login.php [QSA,L]
    
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    
    
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    
    
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    
    
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all
    
    
        Order allow,deny
        Deny from all

```
# Rules to disable directory browsing
Options -Indexes

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Rules to protect wp-includes
    RewriteRule ^wp-admin/includes/ - [F]
    RewriteRule !^wp-includes/ - [S=3]
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !^(.*)wp-includes/ms-files.php
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/[^/]+\.php$ - [F]
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/js/tinymce/langs/.+\.php - [F]
    RewriteRule ^wp-includes/theme-compat/ - [F]

    # Rules to prevent php execution in uploads
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/uploads/(.*).php(.?) - [F]

    # Rules to block unneeded HTTP methods
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|DELETE|TRACK) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

    # Rules to block suspicious URIs
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\.\/ [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*\.(bash|git|hg|log|svn|swp|cvs) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} etc/passwd [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boot\.ini [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\:  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\:  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\:  [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig_[a-zA-Z_]{1,21}(=|%3D) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode.*\(.*\) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\[|\]|\(|\)|<|>|ê|"|;|\?|\*|=$).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(&#x22;|&#x27;|&#x3C;|&#x3E;|&#x5C;|&#x7B;|&#x7C;).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%24&x).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(127\.0).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|concat|insert|union|declare).* [NC]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^loggedout=true
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^action=rp
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !^.*wordpress_logged_in_.*$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://maps\.googleapis\.com(.*)$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]

    # Rules to help reduce spam
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} POST
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)wp-comments-post\.php*
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^(.*)mywebsite.com.* 
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://jetpack\.wordpress\.com/jetpack-comment/ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F]
</IfModule>
```

Let's consider that rewrite engine is not enabled in the host provider. I got the same result in my localhost. In localhost I have several other projects that use rewrite rules extensively. In wordpress I get `404 Not Found`

Comment: You must be sure that your hosting provider has the revrite engine enabled.

Comment: Place `RewriteEngine On` outside the `IfModule` condition. If you get a 500 Internal Server Error, `mod_rewrite` is *not* enabled.

Comment: You can also try `<?php print_r(apache_get_modules()); ?>` and check if there exists `mod_rewrite`.

Comment: @NETCreator Worth mentioning that won't work if PHP is running as CGI.

Comment: Can you show us the whole rewrite rules in .htaccess ?

Comment: Could you give us a list of plugins you currently have installed?

Comment: @TheDeadMedic, I alreay have `RewriteEngine On` inside and outside of the `IfModule`

Comment: @kraftner, you can now see the whole htaccess in the **EDIT1** part of the question.

Comment: These rules look very complex. I'd just try to remove them and if this makes it work add them back in to see which is the offending one and then investigate it further.

Comment: @kraftner, I removed everything from htaccess except `RewriteEngine On`, but nothing happend!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I emptied both `permalink` and `itsec_hide_backend` fields in `options` table through phpMyAdmin. Then I removed everything from `.htaccess` and then logged into my blog's dashboard by typing `/wp-login.php` then I set permalink through `Settings->Permalink` to `/%postname%/`.

Voila! Everything works fine now. ;-)